# I am getting a missing keyword error in this case expression

Tags: sql, case

I am getting a missing keyword error in this case expression.

What is the reason?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION = 'TOY')
       THEN
          CASE
             WHEN MM.MODEL_DESCRIPTION = 'SCION' THEN MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION = 'SCION'
             WHEN MM.MODEL_DESCRIPTION <> 'SCION' THEN MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION
          END
    ELSE MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION END) AS MAKE
FROM table_make MM where value ='test';
```

Comment: Give us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in one of your when clauses you have put another Boolean expression as your THEN output so instead of saying then show 'SCION', you put then show Boolean expression which doesn't make sense.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION = 'TOY')
   THEN
      CASE
         WHEN MM.MODEL_DESCRIPTION = 'SCION' THEN 'SCION' --edit here
         WHEN MM.MODEL_DESCRIPTION <> 'SCION' THEN MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION
      END
ELSE MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION END) AS MAKE

FROM table_make MM where value ='test';
```

Answer (score 0):

your case statement missed two points

1.`end` will be after `else`

2.and another else will come for 1st `case when`

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION = 'TOY'
               THEN
                  CASE
                     WHEN MM.MODEL_DESCRIPTION = 'SCION' then
                     'SCION'
                     WHEN MM.MODEL_DESCRIPTION <> 'SCION' THEN MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION

            ELSE MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION END
else null end AS MAKE -- this else for 1st case
  FROM table_make MM where value ='test';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it with an AND

```
CASE 
    WHEN MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION = 'TOY' AND MM.MODEL_DESCRIPTION = 'SCION' 
        THEN 'SCION'
    ELSE MM.MAKE_DESCRIPTION
END
```